# Rsyslog not forwarding log messages to Loki (Grafana)

Tags: rsyslog, grafana-loki, promtail

I have set up a Loki server (part of Grafana's monitoring stack) to aggregate and query log data. However, I am experiencing issues with log forwarding from rsyslog to Loki. It seems that the log messages are not being received by Loki, and I'm unable to troubleshoot the problem.

loki-config.yaml

```
auth_enabled: false

server:
  http_listen_port: 3100

common:
  ring:
    instance_addr: 127.0.0.1
    kvstore:
      store: inmemory
  replication_factor: 1
  path_prefix: /tmp/loki

schema_config:
  configs:
  - from: 2020-05-15
    store: boltdb-shipper
    object_store: filesystem
    schema: v11
    index:
      prefix: index_
      period: 24h
```

promtail-config.yaml

```
server:
  http_listen_port: 9080
  grpc_listen_port: 0

positions:
  filename: /tmp/positions.yaml

clients:
  - url: http://gateway:3100/loki/api/v1/push
    tenant_id: tenant1

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: flog_scrape
    docker_sd_configs:
      - host: unix:///var/run/docker.sock
        refresh_interval: 5s
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: ['__meta_docker_container_name']
        regex: '/(.*)'
        target_label: 'container'
```

I have followed the official documentation to configure rsyslog to forward log messages to Loki using HTTP. I added the following line to my rsyslog configuration file:

```
*.* action(type="omhttp" target="http://localhost:3100/loki/api/v1/push" contentType="application/json")
```

I have also restarted the rsyslog service after making the changes:
`sudo systemctl restart rsyslog`

However, when I check Loki's logs or use the LogCLI utility to query log data, I do not see any log messages from rsyslog. I have verified that rsyslog is receiving log messages from various sources, and other local log files are being updated as expected.

**Error:**

2023/07/24 04:21:28 Error response from server: empty ring
() attempts remaining: 0
2023/07/24 04:21:28 Query failed: run out of attempts while querying the server

Verified that Loki is running and listening on the correct port (3100) for log ingestion.
Verified that rsyslog is receiving log messages from other sources.
Restarted the rsyslog service after making configuration changes.

**Expected Outcome:**

I expect log messages sent by rsyslog to be forwarded to Loki and visible when querying log data using LogCLI.

Any suggestions or insights on what could be causing this issue or how to further troubleshoot it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!